# How to push objects into array inside of a JavaScript Prototype?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have an Angular Factory whose job is to save special objects and retrieve them later.
 (Used to save the users workflow when he switches views).

Basically I need to save objects with a name, as well as an array of tags. My problem is with the saving the tags into the array part.

The Prototype constructor:

```
// define the TagsObject constructor function
var TagsObject = function(name, tag) {
    this.name = name;
    this.tags = [].push(tag);
    return this;
};
```

Full factory code:

```
.factory('TagFactory', [function() {

    // Init TagFactory:
    var tagContainers = [];

    // define the TagsObject constructor function
    var TagsObject = function(name, tag) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tags = [].push(tag);
        return this;
    };

    console.log('tagFactory');
    console.log(TagsObject);

    var saveTags = function(name, tag) {

        tagContainers.push(new TagsObject(name, tag));

        console.log('saveTags:');
        console.log(tagContainers);
    };

    var getTags = function(name) {
        console.log(name);
        return this;
    };

    return {
        saveTags : saveTags,
        getTags  : getTags
    };
}]);
```

In a different controller I now save some data into a `new Prototype` inside of the TagFactory:

```
TagFactory.saveTags('TEST', tagObj);
```

Now back in my Factory, where you see the `console.log(nameTagContainers);` the following is the log:

```
[TagsObject]
    0: TagsObject
    tags: 1
    name: "TEST"
    __proto__: TagsObject
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

^ tags is an Array, but it's showing 1, instead of the Object details... do you see where I went wrong?

---

---

***UPDATE:*** This question was answered below by [Kauê Gimenes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055711/kau%C3%AA-gimenes), however I'm sharing the extra code I added to fix my other problem.

Which was every time a new tag was selected for a currently selected name, it generated a new Prototype, instead of saving the tag into an existing Prototype:

```
var saveTags = function(name, tag) {

    console.log(tagContainers.length);

    if (tagContainers.length != 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < tagContainers.length; i++) {
            if (tagContainers[i].name == name) {
                console.log('Found existing name! Add tag to existing obj');
                tagContainers[i].tags.push(tag);
                break;
            } else {
                console.log('New name, create new obj');
                tagContainers.push(new TagsObject(name, tag));
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log('New name, init: create the first obj');
        tagContainers.push(new TagsObject(name, tag));
    }

    console.log(' ');
    console.log('tagContainers:');
    console.log(tagContainers);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
// define the TagsObject constructor function
var TagsObject = function(name, tag) {
    this.name = name;
    this.tags = [tag];
    return this;
};
```

The best way to **initialize** an array is to include the elements inside the brackets

```
[ 1 , 2 , 3 ]
```

But in case you want to initialize with **n** elements you could use the `concat` function.

```
[ 1 ].concat([ 2 , 3 , 4 ])
```

The result would be:

```
[ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ]
```

Comment: Ah yeah that does work, and does answer this question... however I just realized I wrote this code wrong. There are several tags which the user can select for 1 name. Right now my code creates a new Prototype every time the user clicks a new tag for just 1 name. Thanks! I need to update my code, and possibly post a new question.

Comment: I include some extra information to make the answer more clear, if you still have any questions about this feel free to ask!

Comment: ah ok so the *n* elements Array could fix my new problem here

Comment: Great! i am happy i was able to solve your problem =)